# Getting current post ID in functions.php

Tags: posts, functions, id

I need to get the current post ID into an array in my functions.php.

```
function filter_query(  $query ) {
    $query['post__not_in'] = array(7);
    return $query;
}
add_filter('wpc_query', 'filter_query', 1 );
```

`get_the_ID();` or `global $post; $id = $post->ID;` didn't work for some reasons.

Comment: Well, that depends... Where are you using the carousel? In a WP widget? Or as a shortcode on a page or in a post?

Comment: Hi @MacPrawn, I'm using the carousel in a widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should work in all cases - whether you are in the loop or not. (In a widget, chances are you are *not* in the loop)

Mind you, outside the loop, this will work very well on single pages or posts, but might not display the post you want on other types of pages. (home page, category pages, ...) In those cases, you might want to add a condition to only run your code on a singular page, using WordPress' [is_singular](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) function...

Anyway, here's a revised version of your code:

```
function filter_query( $query ) {
    if(in_the_loop()) $post_id = get_the_ID();
    else $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
    if($post_id) {
        if(empty($query['post__not_in'])) $query['post__not_in'] = array(); // that way if someone else already has stuff in $query['post__not_in'], we won't override it but append to it...
        $query['post__not_in'][] = $post_id;
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('wpc_query', 'filter_query', 1 );
```

Hope this helps!